# How to filter out the array with lowest date value using SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

Ive run a query which results in an array of objects, i tried to filter out the objects in the array based on the lowest date value but i'm not able to get the required output. I tried to use min(tb2.date as Date) in the query to filter out based on lowest date with respects of each 'title', but it returns only one object with lowest date value.

The query I've used is :

```
SELECT 
tb2.date as Date, 
tb1.title as title, 
tb1.descp as descp

FROM 
table1 tb1
LEFT JOIN table2  tb2 ON ( tb2.id = tb1.id )

WHERE 
tb1.id = x

ORDER BY 
tb1.date, 
tb1.status ASC
```

The output i got is :

```
Array(
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Date] => 2020-05-05
                 [title] => new test
                [descp] => req changes
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Date] => 2020-05-06
                [title] => new test 
                 [descp] => req changes
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [Date] => 2020-05-08
                 [title] => Project 
               [descp] => asdasdasda
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [Date] => 2020-05-18
                [title] => Project 
                [descp] => asdasdasda
            )
)
```

The output I required is :

```
 [0] => Array
            (
                [Date] => 2020-05-05
                 [title] => new test
                [descp] => req changes
            )
[1] => Array
            (
                [Date] => 2020-05-08
                 [title] => Project 
               [descp] => asdasdasda
            )
```

Comment: Can we see the actual query?

Comment: Where did `orgDate` come from

Comment: There is only one object with the lowest date value. Your required result does not conform with your specified requirement ?? Please explain

Comment: *Ive run a query which results in an array of objects* MySQL have no "array of objects" datatype. It returns rowset which is treated as array by PHP.

Comment: `2020-05-05` is the lowest date .....`2020-05-08` is the THIRD lowest date ??

Comment: Seems like `title` is involved here as well, but not used in the query !?!?!?!?!?

Comment: @RiggsFolly based on the 'title' i need to filterout lowest date for each. that is , here two 'title' can be seen 'project' & 'new test'. for object with 'title' project has got two dates(2020-05-08 & 2020-05-18) so i want only which having the smaller date. similarly for the other one also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test

```sql
SELECT MIN(tb2.date) AS `date`, 
       tb1.title, 
       tb1.`desc`
FROM table1 tb1
LEFT JOIN table2 tb2 USING ( id )
WHERE tb1.id = x     -- ??? transferred from the question text as-is
GROUP BY tb1.title, tb1.`desc`
ORDER BY `date`
```

Comment: Thanks @Akina. By using GROUP BY and MIN() I could filter the lowest date for each title.